# Integrity constraint violation: 1048 and Default value

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, fosrestbundle

i try to create an entity with fosrestBundle, symfony and doctrine

If i give all the datas in my json, it works

I have one field 'test' that cannot be null and it has the defeault value "0"

in my entity, i have :

```
/**
 * @var smallint
 */
private $test= '0';
```

in my orm.yml file :

```
test:
        type: smallint
        nullable: false
        options:
            default: '0'
        column: ind_archive
```

And when i call my WS without :
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 field 'test' cannot be null

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: update your schema after the changes. did you?

Comment: it's ok, i probably add cache problem. Finaly, i used boolean value withprivate $test= false;